# I want to populate custom div based subcategory list as per selected main category list with Json callback

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have created a custom item list. It's not a regular html list element, it's custom div based item list with Jquery onclick event. This is my Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).find("div[id^='cat']").live('click', function()
  { 
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
$.getJSON('get_categories.php', {catName:$("#"+currentId).text()}, function(data) 
{
    $.each(data.CatList, function(i,itemList)
    {
        var tblRow =
        "<div class='shop_options' id='cat" + itemList.id + "' onclick=''"  +">"
        +itemList.sub_cat+"</div>";
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#subCatList");

    });

});

  });

 });
```

I am able to append the sub category as per the main category item with onclick. But the problem is after clicking on one category whenever I click on any other category to populate the sub category data then it just amends the other category data as well as with previously selected main category item list.

For example if I select **Fruits**, then it displays the data **Mango, Banana, Orange** and again whenever I select any other category like **Flowers** then it displays Flowers's subcategory list **Rose, Lotus, Marigold** underneath Fruits subcategory list.

I want to clear the previously selected category items. How to do that, please give your experts advice. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$("#subCatList").empty();
```

before append.

Comment: I have used it but now I am can see just the last one sub category item e.g Orange or Marigold. I can't see the other items. Do I need to use any loop now?

Comment: Just use this code to empty/clear the data and then use your normal code for looping.

Answer (score 0):

use `html()` to make the div empty

```
$.getJSON('get_categories.php', {catName:$("#"+currentId).text()}, function(data) 
{

  $("#subCatList").html()  //here add this

  $.each(data.CatList, function(i,itemList)
  {
    var tblRow =
    "<div class='shop_options' id='cat" + itemList.id + "' onclick=''"  +">"
    +itemList.sub_cat+"</div>";
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#subCatList");

  });

});
```

Comment: Please can you clarify at line 3. I don't see any closing brackets for html().

Comment: sorry my bad.. tht bracket was a mistake.. updated.. what the code does is after calling the `getJSON` function it empties the div with id subCatlist... and thn your loop appends the rest of the categories..